# Hot fix in weblogic

Tags: java, oracle, maven, weblogic-10.x

I am running my project on weblogic , the source code of the project is at 'C:/Source Code' and when I run mvn clean install the .ear file is getting created in C:/Ear/abc.ear, and I have imported the project in eclipe from C:/Source, the abc.ear is autodeployed in C:/oracle/Middleware.../Autodeploy

Now whenever i make changes in any java class i have to manually replace the class file which is build in eclipse to C:/oracle/Middleware.../Autodeploy.

Is there any way to automate this so that the changed class file would be automatically available to the C:/oracle/Middleware.../Autodeploy/abc.ear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Eclipse development with WebLogic, install the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse to better integrate with WebLogic. You will no longer need to use the autodeploy and your application will update automatically.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html